# Xcode 7.3 transition alway modal

Tags: xcode, uistoryboardsegue

I have an app that runs fine inside of Xcode 6.3 that is running on MacOS X 10.5. When I copied this same program code to another Mac machine that is running EL Capitan v. 10.11.5 and Xcode 7.3.1, prepareForSegue will display a modal transition versus its configured "Show (e.g. Push)"!

I deleted the UINavigationController, and then reinstituted it by "embedding" it via the tableViewController. I also reestablished the "Show (e.g. Push)" Storyboard Segue Kind between the initial view controller, and the UINavigationController. Unfortunately, the transition is alway a Modal segue (the tableviewController opens from the bottom of the screen).

Please help me with this issue! Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Thank you